# How to get all form elements values using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Here is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' >
<head>
    <title>HTML Form Builder</title>
    <link href='css/font1.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='css/font2.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/style.min.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/form.min.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/style1.css' type='text/css' media='all' id='css-theme'/>
    <link type='text/css' href='css/redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/tipsy.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.metadata.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.validate.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.tipsy.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.json-2.3.min.js'></script>

    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/main.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function(){
        changeInnerHTML('doctor_id');
        changeInnerHTML('hospital_id');
        changeInnerHTML('clinic_id');
        changeInnerHTML('stockist_id');
        changeInnerHTML('chemist_id');
        changeInnerHTML('bloodbank_id');
        changeInnerHTML('dialysis_id');
        
    });
    function changeInnerHTML(id)
    {
        if($('#dialog_box_'+id).length)
        {
            var tmp=id.split('_');
             $.get('getDataValues.php?ref='+tmp[0],function(data,status){
                $('#dialog_box_'+id).html(data);
            });
        }
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id='container'>
    

        <h1 id="form-name" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); box-shadow: none; border: none; margin: 8px 15px;">New Form</h1>
        <form method="POST" id="preview_form" novalidate="novalidate">
            
            
        <div class="row" style="display: block;"><label class="field" for="textarea_1">textarea_1</label><span class="textArea" data=""><textarea id="dialog_box_textarea_1" name="textarea_1" data="{&quot;validate&quot;:{&quot;required&quot;:false,&quot;messages&quot;:{}}}"></textarea></span></div><div class="row" style="display: block;"><label class="field" for="radiobutton_1">radiobutton_1</label><span class="radioButton" data="" id="radiobutton_1"><label class="option" for="radiobutton_1_option_1"><input class="radio" id="dialog_box_radiobutton_1_option_1" type="radio" name="radiobutton_1" value="Option 1" data="{&quot;validate&quot;:{&quot;required&quot;:false,&quot;messages&quot;:{}}}">Option 1</label><label class="option" for="radiobutton_1_option_2"><input class="radio" id="radiobutton_1_option_2" type="radio" name="radiobutton_1" value="Option 2">Option 2</label><label class="option" for="radiobutton_1_option_3"><input class="radio" id="radiobutton_1_option_3" type="radio" name="radiobutton_1" value="Option 3">Option 3</label></span></div><div class="row" style="display: block;"><label class="field" for="checkboxgroup_1">checkboxgroup_1</label><span class="checkBoxGroup" data="" id="checkboxgroup_1"><label class="option" for="checkboxgroup_1_option_1"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="checkboxgroup_1[]" id="dialog_box_checkboxgroup_1_option_1" value="Option 1" data="{&quot;validate&quot;:{&quot;required&quot;:false,&quot;messages&quot;:{}}}">Option 1</label><label class="option" for="checkboxgroup_1_option_2"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="checkboxgroup_1[]" id="checkboxgroup_1_option_2" value="Option 2">Option 2</label><label class="option" for="checkboxgroup_1_option_3"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="checkboxgroup_1[]" id="checkboxgroup_1_option_3" value="Option 3">Option 3</label></span></div><div class="row" style="display: block;"><label class="field" for="dropdown_1">dropdown_1</label><span class="dropDown" data=""><select id="dialog_box_dropdown_1" name="dropdown_1" data="{&quot;validate&quot;:{&quot;required&quot;:false,&quot;messages&quot;:{}}}"><option value="Option 1">Option 1</option><option value="Option 2">Option 2</option><option value="Option 3">Option 3</option></select></span></div><input type="button" class="button blue" value="Submit" id="submit-form"><input type='hidden' id='tname' name='tname' value='surveyForm_2' /></form></div> <!--container-->

<script type='text/javascript' src='js/form.min.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here the code which will get all form field values:

```
 $("#hidAll").append($("#preview_form :input").map(function () {
     if ($(this).val() != 'Submit') {
         if ($(this).is('select')) {
             var aa = $(this).children('option').map(function () {
                 return $(this).val();
             }).get().join("|");
             return $(this).attr('name') + '|' + aa;
         } else if ($(this).is('input:checkbox')) {
             return $(this).attr('name').substring(0, $(this).attr('name').length - 2) + '|' + $(this).val();
         } else {
             return $(this).attr('name') + '|' + $(this).val();
         }
     }
 }).get().join(","));
 alert($("#hidAll").html());
```

From this I am getting the output value as follows:

```
textfield_1|dgdfg,
checkboxgroup_1|Option 1,
checkboxgroup_1|Option 2,
checkboxgroup_1|Option 3,
radiobutton_1|Option 1,
radiobutton_1|Option 2,
radiobutton_1|Option 3,
dropdown_1|Option 1!Option 2!Option 3
```

I want the out as following:

```
textfield_1|dgdfg,
checkboxgroup_1|Option 1!Option 2!Option 3,
radiobutton_1|Option 1!Option 2!Option 3,
dropdown_1|Option 1!Option 2!Option 3
```

Comment: Before writing a form-serializer yourself, did you have a look at: [`.serialize`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)?

Comment: What are you doing with the output? If you're sending this with AJAX, there are easier ways.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

You can use a serialize() function of JQuery:

```
    var datastring = $("#preview_form").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "your url.php",
            data: datastring,
            success: function(data) {
                 alert('Data send');
            }
        });
```

And read in PHP:

```
echo $_POST['datastring']['dialog_box_textarea_1'];
echo $_POST['datastring']['radiobutton_1'];
........
```

And get ***data-**** to tag HTML5 you can see this example:

```
<div id="texto" data-author="Ricardo Miranda" data-date="2012-06-21">
<h4>Lorem ipsum</h4>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ius integre eligendi et,
    sea ut expetendis conclusionemque,
    mel at ornatus invenire. His ad moderatius definiebas omittantur,
    liber saepe albucius sea cu.
    Audire tamquam dolores vis ne, mediocrem consulatu eum ex.
    Duo te agam saepe convenire, et fugit iisque his.
 </p>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    alert("The text is write " + $('#texto').data('author'));
});
```

And

```
<div id="texto" data-author='{"nombre":"Ricardo","apellido":"Miranda"}' data-date="2012-06-21">
   ...
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    alert("The text is write " + $('#texto').data('author').apellido + ", " +
        ('#texto').data('author').nombre);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Wow.... I never knew about `.serialize()` until just now... I've been gathering inputs by their IDs over and over.... ommyyygeerrrddd

Comment: Awesome! The only thing is I think it would be `echo $_POST['dialog_box_textarea_1'];` without `datastring`

Comment: You've saved my day, one interesting thing is that you can select which form fields to serialize just not defining "name" in that tag, serialize function only takes elements with name defined. 
For example I have a date picker and a hidden field where I put the formatted date, just removing the name from the date picker and defining name in the hidden field, serialize only gathers the hidden field not the datepicker.

Comment: Isn't this serializing the form to POST format? I want to send it as JSON which I don't thing there is a serializer for it

Answer (score 15):

I know you're using jQuery but for those who want a **pure Javascript** solution:

```
// Serialize form fields as URI argument/HTTP POST data
function serializeForm(form) {
    var kvpairs = [];
    for ( var i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i++ ) {
        var e = form.elements[i];
        if(!e.name || !e.value) continue; // Shortcut, may not be suitable for values = 0 (considered as false)
        switch (e.type) {
            case 'text':
            case 'textarea':
            case 'password':
            case 'hidden':
                kvpairs.push(encodeURIComponent(e.name) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(e.value));
                break;
            case 'radio':
            case 'checkbox':
                if (e.checked) kvpairs.push(encodeURIComponent(e.name) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(e.value));
                break;
            /*  To be implemented if needed:
            case 'select-one':
                ... document.forms[x].elements[y].options[0].selected ...
                break;
            case 'select-multiple':
                for (z = 0; z < document.forms[x].elements[y].options.length; z++) {
                    ... document.forms[x].elements[y].options[z].selected ...
                } */
                break;
        }
    }
    return kvpairs.join("&");
}
```

Answer (score 8):

jQuery has very helpful function called [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/).

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/55xnJ/2/

```
//Just type:
$("#preview_form").serialize();

//to get result:
single=Single&multiple=Multiple&multiple=Multiple3&check=check2&radio=radio1
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this for getting form input text value to JavaScript object...

```
var fieldPair = {};
$("#form :input").each(function() {
    if($(this).attr("name").length > 0) {
        fieldPair[$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).val();
    }
});

console.log(fieldPair);
```

Comment: Cache `$( this )` in a variable so you're not creating a new jQuery object with every `$( this )` call. i.e. `var $this = $( this ); ... $this.attr( 'name' ) ... $this.val()`.

Answer (score 3):

Add this on to the end of it:

```
var array = $("#hidAll").html();

x = array.split(',');
key=s="";
for (i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
  oldkey = key;
  key = x[i].split('|')[0];
  if (oldkey==key) s+='!';
  else s+=',\n'+key+'|';
  s+=x[i].split('|')[1];
}
s = s.substring(1);
$('#hidAll').html(a);
```

Answer (score 2):

I needed to get the form data as some sort of object. I used this:

```
$('#preview_form').serializeArray().reduce((function(acc, val) {
  acc[val.name.replace('[', '_').replace(']', '')] = val.value;
  return acc;
}), {});
```

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).serialize(...).reduce is not a function`. What am I missing?

Comment: @dearsina i's been a while, but I would check that the form is an object (`name="contact[name]"`,  (`name="contact[email]"`)

Answer (score 1):

The answer already been accepted, I just write a short technique for the same purpose.

```
var fieldPair = '';
$(":input").each(function(){
fieldPair += $(this).attr("name") + ':' + $(this).val() + ';';
});

console.log(fieldPair);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use $(formName).serializeArray() or $(formName).serialize(),
you must add `name='inputName'` on your input element. or will not work!

Answer (score -1):

if you want get all values from form in simple array you may be do something like this.

```
function getValues(form) {
    var listvalues = new Array();
    var datastring = $("#" + form).serializeArray();
    var data = "{";
    for (var x = 0; x < datastring.length; x++) {
        if (data == "{") {
            data += "\"" + datastring[x].name + "\": \"" + datastring[x].value + "\"";
        }
        else {
            data += ",\"" + datastring[x].name + "\": \"" + datastring[x].value + "\"";
        }
    }
    data += "}";
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    listvalues.push(data);
    return listvalues;
};
```

Comment: Josue -- I'm not sure why this is getting downvoted, (You are a first time user and we should be encouraging positive answers), but maybe because the accepted answer is better (i.e. this does not add anything to the discussion), or maybe there is not enough information about why your proposal works better than the original code or other answers.

Comment: The method what I posted, returns values in a similar way, except that replaces the symbol | by the of :