How To get form field values from parent of cloned form button?
So I have the following form. The form is cloneable, so there may be several on the page. When the "Save" button is clicked, I can get the form, and the value of the form ID attribute. But how do I get the form fields and their values? I am hing a heck of a time with the proper syntax. So how would I get the .val of the field "Model"?
<form class="SignificantDiv" name="VechicleForm2" id="VechicleForm2" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="IDNum" value="37">
  <input type="hidden" name="MbrNum" value="42">
  <fieldset class="FormTbl" id="EditProfileFormTbl">
    <ul>
      <li class="col25" title="Vechicle year">
        <label for="Year" id="YearLbl" class="bregLbl">Year</label>
        <input class="bnotes" type="text" id="Year" name="Year" value="1963" />
      </li>
      <li class="col25" title="Vechicle Make">
        <label for="Make" id="MakeLbl" class="bregLbl">Make</label>
        <input class="bnotes" type="text" id="Make" name="Make" value="Dodge" />
      </li>
      <li class="col25" title="Vechicle Model">
        <label for="Model" id="ModelLbl" class="bregLbl">Model</label>
        <input class="bnotes" type="text" id="Model" name="Model" value="Dart" />
      </li>
      <li class="col25" title="Vechicle Trim Level">
        <label for="Trim" id="TrimLbl" class="bregLbl">Trim</label>
        <input class="bnotes" type="text" id="Trim" name="Trim" value="GT" />
      </li>
      <li class="col100" title="More Info">
        <label for="Comments" id="CommentsLbl" class="bregLbl">Comments</label>
        <textarea id="ExtraInfo" name="ExtraInfo" class="bnotes" rows="1"></textarea>
      </li>
      <li class="col50" title="vehicle model">
        <input class="delete" type="button" id="DeleteButton" name="DeleteButton" title="Delete this vehicle" value="Delete" />
      </li>
      <li class="col50" title="vehicle model">
        <input class="send" type="button" id="SaveButton" name="SaveButton" title="Save this vehicle" value="Save" />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </fieldset>
</form>

Here is my JQuery:
    $(".send").on("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("Save Button Clicked");
        
        var TheForm = $(this).closest("form")[0];
    
        //This doesn't work
        //var Model = $(this).closest("form")[0].find('input[name="Model"]').val();
        
        //This doesn't work
        //var Model = TheForm.find('input[name="Model"]').val();
        
        //This doesn't work
        //var Model = TheForm.Model.val();
        
        //This doesn't work
        //var Model = $(TheForm).("#SendTo").val();
        
        //This one returns that there is an object, but .val() is undefined
        // $(TheForm).children("Model").val();
        
        //This one returns that there is an object, but .val() is undefined
        //var Model = $(this).closest("form").children("Model").val();
        
        alert("I need some help with the correct syntax!");
        
    });


IDs are supposed to be unique. Don't use IDs in HTML that you expect to clone, use classes instead.

You're all around the solution, but you're confusing DOM and jQuery syntax. You want $(this).closest("form").find('input[name="Model"]').val() (the [0] converts the jQuery object to a DOM element, which prevents you from using jQuery .find().

If you are looking for a jQuery based solution then have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14936494/how-to-get-all-form-elements-values-using-jquery . The jQuery methods .serialize() and .serializeArray() might be what you are looking for.

@Barmar, Thanks!! $(this).closest("form").find('input[name="Model"]').val() did the trick.
Can you repost as an answer so I can accept it as the answer?

You do not need to use an ID property on form elements.
Because there is precisely a hierarchical relationship between the form and its inputs, which are based on their name.
example:
document.forms[0].Model.value;

But prefer to use FormData() API to get all values ​​directly


const templateForm = document.querySelector('#form-template');

// create 2 forms ...or more
document.body.append( document.importNode(templateForm.content, true) );
document.body.append( document.importNode(templateForm.content, true) );

// give them a legend text
document.forms[0].querySelector('legend').textContent = 'form one';
document.forms[1].querySelector('legend').textContent = 'form two';


document.addEventListener('submit', e =>   // get form all inputs values 
  {
  e.preventDefault();
  const formValues = Object.fromEntries(new FormData(e.srcElement).entries());
  console.clear();
  console.log( formValues );
  })
  
/* -------------------------------- also ----
[...document.forms].forEach( form => 
  {
  form.addEventListener('submit', e =>   // get form all inputs values 
    {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formValues = Object.fromEntries(new FormData(form).entries());
    console.clear();
    console.log( formValues );
    })
  });
----------------------------------------- */
body {
  font-family : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size   : 12px;
  }
form {
  display : inline-block;
  }
fieldset {
  margin  : 0.7rem; 
  padding : 1em; 
  width   : 15rem;    
  } 
label { 
  margin      : .8rem 0 0 0;  
  display     : block;
  font-size   : .9rem;
  font-weight : bold;
  }
label * {
  box-sizing : border-box;
  display    : block;
  font-size  : 1rem;
  width      : 100%;
  padding    : .1rem .3rem;
  }
textarea {
  height    : 5rem;
  min-width : 100%;
  }
button{ 
  margin         : 1rem 0 0 0;  
  width          : 100%;
  text-transform : uppercase;
  font-size      : 1rem;
  }
legend { 
  padding : 0 .5rem;
  color   : red;
  }
<template id="form-template">
  <form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="IDNum"  value="37">
    <input type="hidden" name="MbrNum" value="42">
    <fieldset >
      <legend> xxx </legend>
      <label>
        Year
        <input name="Year" value="1963" placeholder="Vechicle year" >
      </label>
      <label>
        Vechicle 
        <input name="Make" value="Dodge" placeholder="Vechicle Make" >
      </label>
      <label>
        Model
        <input name="Model" value="Dart" placeholder="Vechicle Model" >
      </label>
      <label>
        Trim 
        <input name="Trim" value="GT" placeholder="Vechicle Trim Level" >
      </label>
      <label>
        Comments
        <textarea name="ExtraInfo" rows="1" placeholder="More Info" ></textarea>
      </label>
      <button title="Delete this vehicle" type="button" name="DeleteButton">Delete</button>
      <button>Save</button>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</template>




Just something that I find useful in this case. If you add the event listener to document instead of each form, adding more forms at a later point, you don't need to also add an event listener to that new form. If there are a lot of forms with different purposes, you could test if the submitted form has the right name.

@chrwahl, As you like. This technique is named event delegation.
